# Continuously add new entries to Django model

Tags: django, django-models

I need some conceptual help understanding how this idea would work. If I have a user make a list and they can add infinite items to each list, how would I want to map out the model?

In my list model I have `user = ForeignKey(User)`, so each instantiation of this list model is attributed to the user currently logged in and they can have a series of lists. However, if they want to add an item to the list, would I have a new model called `add_item` and make the `list_name = foreignkey(user.listname)`?

```
#New List Model
    class NewList(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(User)
        list_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, default = "Enter List Name")
        picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_images', blank=True)

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.list_name

#New Item Model
    class NewItem(models.Model):

        lists = models.ForeignKey(NewList)
        # list_name = models.OneToOneField(User.list_name)

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.user.username
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understands right,

```
class MyList(models.Model):
    user = ForeignKey(User)
    list_name = CharField(...)
    ....

    def list_items(self):
        return self.mylistitems_set.all()

class MyListItem(models.Model):
    mylist = ForeignKey(MyList)
    item_name = .....
    ....
```

A user may create as many lists an he/she wants and may add any number of items to a specific list. So logic is you create any number of lists (a record on MyList) and add as many items as you want to it through `MyListItem`.

Following is a good way to do this:

```
alist = MyList(......)
alist.mylistitem_set.create(...)  # add an item to alist
```

[Django Reverse relations documentation is here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward)

**Update:** Taking all lists of a specific user

```
user = User.objects.get() # a specific user
user.mylist_set.all() # returns all lists belong to that user.
```

You have to read more about reverse relations in django.

Comment: Ahh, this is very close to what I am wanting, if not exactly. Does the ForeignKey populate based on the __unicode__ function?

Comment: What do you mean with that? What do you try to achieve? I added a method under `MyList` that allows you to retrieve all `MyListItems`  related to that list. You can alter it or add similar methods according to your needs.

Comment: I'm trying to get a user to only see lists associated with their username and then add an item to the given list. The code I have added in edit only shows all the lists available and that's it when adding a new list item.

Comment: Just wanted to follow-up. Did my final implementation on my site to ensure I could print the data per individual users. It works flawlessly. Thanks!

Comment: The key in here is creating a proper database table structure and use django database ORM in a proper way. As I said, read all parts related to model structure and query execution ;)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds about right. If your model is eg named `MyList`, then:

```
my_user = ... # obtain a user object
my_item = MyList(user=my_user)
my_item.save()
```

Comment: Ok great. Just to verify, how would I create a field that inherits the listname of the user? I said list_name = foreignkey(user.listname), but wasn't sure if that's accurate.

Comment: Tbh, this part of your question I didn't quite get. What exactly do you want to do with such a field? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/relations/

Comment: I'm having trouble conceptually understanding this. Say a user enters a series of lists, "shopping", "music", "food". I want them to be able to open up the list called "music" and add a new item. Then add another, then add another... etc. The NewItem model would need to show all the lists associated with that user.